# How can I easily switch between Firebase function emulator endpoints and my delpoyment function endpoints?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cli

In my React app, I call
`https://us-central1-<project-name>.cloudfunctions.net/<express-app-name>/<function-endpoint>` which is the deployed endpoint format for all my Firebase functions. When I'm using the Firebase emulator however, this changes to `http://localhost:5001/<project-name>/us-central1/<express-app-name>/<function-endpoint>`. I have to manually switch this value when deploying my app. How can I avoid this?

Comment: The emulator is open source.  You can make it do whatever you want.  Otherwise, you can't change the behavior.

Comment: You'll typically want to detect what environment you code is running in, and then putting in the right URL for that environment. But it's hard to say how that'd work for you without seeing the code of what you do now.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Yeah I don't know why I didn't just think to check window.location and then hardcode the endpoint. That makes sense, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll typically want to detect what environment you code is running in, and then putting in the right URL for that environment.

If you isolate this code correctly, it's usually a single `if` somewhere early on in the app's lifecycle.